# How can I set environment variables to a buffer-local scope in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Emacs, I want to vary the values of my environment variables in different buffers.

My emacs environment depends on environment variables (flymake, compile etc), however I want to be able to be able to have multiple projects open at once in one emacs session but these projects might have conflicting environments.

For example something like different INCLUDE_PATH environment variables for flymake.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this by making `process-environment` buffer-local:

```
(defun setup-some-mode-env ()
  (make-local-variable 'process-environment)
  ;; inspect buffer-file-name and add stuff to process-environment as necessary
  ...)
(add-hook 'some-major-mode 'setup-some-mode-env)
```

A more elaborate example is this code that imports the Guile environment setup created by an external script. The script is designed to be "sourced" in the shell, but here its result gets imported into a single Emacs buffer:

```
(defun my-guile-setup ()
  (make-local-variable 'process-environment)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (call-process "bash" nil t nil "-c"
          "source ~/work/guileenv; env | egrep 'GUILE|LD_LIBRARY_PATH'")
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (not (eobp))
      (setq process-environment
        (cons (buffer-substring (point) (line-end-position))
          process-environment))
      (forward-line 1))))

(add-hook 'guile-hook 'my-guile-setup)
```

Comment: This "process-environment" variable is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For anyone that's only trying to affect the `M-x compile` environment, you can simply use the `compilation-environment` variable. See the last paragraph [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html) for details. You can also make this vairable buffer-local

Comment: @Felipe Good point, though the OP did specifically refer to flymake, which is not part of `compilation-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

I put the following in `.dir-locals.el` at the root of the tree where I want to define some environment vars:

```
;; variables local to this directory and its children
((nil . ((eval . (setenv "SOME_VARIABLE" "TRUE")))))
```

This will warn the first time you open a file in that directory tree. After you accept, the given environment var will be defined for each buffer you open there.

Comment: You're setting the global value.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to temporary change the environment when you spawn an external command. The command will inherit the current environment. Remember that Emacs is a single-treaded application, so we don't have to worry about race conditions etc.

You can pick one of two ways of doing this:

1) Write you own functions like `my-compile` that changes the environment temporarily and calls the normal compile command.

2) Modify the low-level process functions and ensure that they modify the environment accordingly. Typically, you can do this with `defadvice`.

Comment: Clearly, the answer of @user4815162342 is better than this, as it appears that Emacs already had a mechanism to handle the environment of subprocesses...

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use *dynamic binding* for those variables.

*Dynamic binding* and *Dynamic scoping* are a bit hard to explain, for explanations see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding and
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Dynamic_scoping).

Comment: This is about *environment* variables, not Lisp variables. There is nothing inherently hard to explain about dynamic binding, in fact it's still the default in Emacs Lisp.

Comment: Right, didn't carefully read the question. But dynamic scoping is hard to explain to people who aren't used to - that it is the default in Elisp doesn't make it easier to understand

Comment: Dynamic scoping has many problems, but being hard to understand is not one of them. It is in fact trivial to understand, which is why it is the default in languages like BASIC, the various shells, Perl, various Lisps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I create a local `process-environment` without necessarily making it `buffer-local`.  The advantage is that the settings only affect the running process and they disappear once the process ends.  In this example, I set the timzezone environmental variable and call the function with `(funcall my-start-process ....)` and everything else is just like `start-process` in terms of arguments and so forth.

```lisp
(let* ((my-start-process
         (lambda (name buffer program &rest program-args)
           (unless (fboundp 'make-process)
             (error "Emacs was compiled without subprocess support"))
           (let* (
               (temp (mapcar 'concat process-environment))
               (newenv
                 (cond
                   ((equal (car (cdr (current-time-zone))) "PDT")
                     (setenv-internal temp "TZ" "UTC+7" t))
                   ((equal (car (cdr (current-time-zone))) "PST")
                     (setenv-internal temp "TZ" "UTC+8" t))))
               (process-environment (or newenv temp)))
             (apply #'make-process
              (append (list :name name :buffer buffer)
              (when program
                (list :command (cons program program-args))))))))
         (proc (funcall my-start-process ...))))
```